# Integration by substitution in two dimensions.

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I want to integrate over the unit square $||(x,y)||_\infty<1$, using the substitution:

$u=\frac{1}{1-xy}$ and $v=\frac{1-x}{1-xy}$.

What is the correct expression for $dxdy$ in terms of $u,v,du,dv$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The term your looking for is $$dxdy=|\frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(u,v)}|dudv$$
The partial derivative-looking term is called a **Jacobian** and is defined as

$$\frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(u,v)}=\begin{vmatrix}
\frac{\partial x}{\partial u} & \frac{\partial x}{\partial v}   \\
\frac{\partial y}{\partial u} & \frac{\partial y}{\partial v}
\end{vmatrix}=\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}\frac{\partial y}{\partial v}-\frac{\partial x}{\partial v}\frac{\partial y}{\partial u}$$

In your case, $$x=1-\frac{v}{u},~~~y=\frac{u-1}{u-v}=1+\frac{v-1}{u-v}$$

And therefore

$$\frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(u,v)}=\frac{v}{u^2}\cdot\frac{u-1}{(u-v)^2}-\frac{-1}{u}\cdot\frac{1-v}{(u-v)^2}=\frac{1}{u^2(u-v)}$$

This can actually be generalized to as many dimensions as you please. In higher dimensions, the Jacobian generalizes to
$$\frac{\partial(y_1,y_2,\ldots y_n)}{\partial (x_1,x_2,\ldots x_n)}=\begin{vmatrix}
\frac{\partial y_1}{\partial x_1} & \frac{\partial y_1}{\partial x_2} & \ldots \frac{\partial y_1}{\partial x_n}   \\
\frac{\partial y_2}{\partial x_1} & \frac{\partial y_2}{\partial x_2} & \ldots \frac{\partial y_2}{\partial x_n}   \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots \vdots \\
\frac{\partial y_n}{\partial x_1} & \frac{\partial y_n}{\partial x_2} & \ldots \frac{\partial y_n}{\partial x_n}
\end{vmatrix}$$

Comment: God bless you. I just suck at computations. <3
Can you believe I had a + instead - for the determinant?

Comment: I need to notify you, I made a minor mistake! I forgot to put the "absolute value" bars on the first Jacobian! The answer found will probably be wrong without these.

Comment: All is well, as $||(x,y)||_\infty<1$  implies $u>1$ and $v \in (0,1)$